# How To Display Both A Username And Their Email In A Custom List

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, custom-list

Salvete!  In one of my custom lists, I want to add a user-account column (where you display properties of a user or group) to display a user's username, but I also need to display the user's email address from his account information.  I know that if I add a second user-account column, I can choose to display the "work e-mail" field, but that necessitates entering the user's name twice - once for the user's username and once for the email.

Is there any way to use the username gotten from the first user-account column to fetch the email for me? Maybe there is some third party solution?

[This post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/add-existing-list-as-a-lookup-column-in-user-profiles) seems relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salvete! I would suggest that you use a workflow which is automatically started when an item in your list is created or updated. The workflow would look at the field with the user's name and from that lookup the user's email. The workflow would then update the listitem's field and complete.

Comment: Ah!  I suppose folks think this is the only way!  I like to accept answers to all my questions, but I also like to get several answers to choose from!

Answer (score 1):

For username , I would use Infopath: Create a single text field. Then in Infopath, select the field. Double click the field name from right, select "function sign" in right side of default value, choose insert function, choose user , username()  function, then Ok. ok.

For email , full name , etc I would create a workflow, find the condition, in the list, who created the item, [created by], then there is a field return type, I would choose, email, full name, string, etc whatever I need.